# Get ranges from List of objects with no gaps:

Tags: c#, .net, linq

Given a list with thousands of objects in the list like these:

```
 var list = new List<PointAddress>();
 list.Add(new PointAddress { Line = 1, Number = 100f });
 list.Add(new PointAddress { Line = 1, Number = 101f });
 list.Add(new PointAddress { Line = 1, Number = 105f });
 list.Add(new PointAddress { Line = 1, Number = 106f });
 list.Add(new PointAddress { Line = 2, Number = 103f });
 list.Add(new PointAddress { Line = 2, Number = 104f });
```

What is the best way to create ranges without gaps(based on Number property) like the following?
If the difference is > 1 in Number property then it is a gap, Number should be in a different group.

Group 1

Line = 1, Number = 100f
  Line = 1, Number = 101f

Group  2

Line = 1, Number = 105f
  Line = 1, Number = 106f

Group 3

Line = 2, Number = 103f
  Line = 2, Number = 104f

Basically if the Gap > 1 then it should be in a different group by Line.

If the line is different then it is a different group.  If Number is adjacent number and Line is the same then it must in the same group as shown in the example. Line 1 is split into 2 groups - Group 1 and Group 2, because Number is not adjacent.

Comment: Why `103.0 .. 104.1` isn't considered as a gap? What is "gap"?

Comment: You mean by GAP, difference is < 2? so 100.0 and 102.0 have a GAP, but 100.0 and 101.9 don't have a GAP?

Comment: Also what about two records that do not have a "gap" but have a different number for `Line` are they grouped together? @Sadek my money is on the difference between two numbers either rounded or truncated to the while number is `> 1` is what constitutes a gap, so `100.4 .. 102.1` would have one. But this is just a guess till we get more information.

Comment: So is `1.1 .. 2.2` considered a gap because it has a distance of 1.1? Also you should put information like "*Difference of 1 is considered a gap in Number property.*" in to the question [as a edit](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/19671181/edit) not as a comment.

Comment: @ScottChamberlain He changed the question and made all numbers int, so  probably just adjacent numbers are grouped. user2934236, you are saying if you sort your list by Number, and then go through and split on any 2 adjacent with > 1 difference, you will get them organized as you want them to be?

Comment: @Sadek the numbers aren't int's they are all floats due to the `f`'s so it is still very much important.

Comment: @user2934236 if an answer helped you, you should mark it as accepted.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that your list is ordered, something like the following should work.

First, a simple generic Linq extension to partition your list:

```
public static IEnumerable<List<T>> Partition<T>( this IEnumerable<T> source , Func<T,T,bool> areAdjacent )
{
  List<T> list = null ;
  T       prev = default(T) ;

  foreach ( T curr in source )
  {
    if ( list == null )
    {
      list = new List<T> {curr} ;
    }
    else if ( areAdjacent(prev,curr) )
    {
      list.Add(curr) ;
    }
    else
    {
      yield return list ;
      list = new List<T> {curr} ;
    }

    prev = curr ;
  }

  if ( list != null )
  {
    yield return list ;
  }

}
```

Then you can invoke it thus

```
List<PointAddress> addressList = GetSomeEnormousList() ;

List<List<PointAddress>> ranges = addressList
                                  .Partition( (prev,curr) => curr.Line == prev.Line && curr.Number - prev.Number == 1.0 )
                                  .ToList()
                                  ;
```

All you need is a lambda that will take two `PointAddress` items and compare them to determine if there's a sequence break or not, returning `true` if the two items are considered to be adjacent or `false` if they are not. How you determine order and the adjacency two items in the ordered set is up to you.

If your list is unordered, you can order it:

```
List<List<PointAddress>> ranges = addressList
                                  .OrderBy( x => x.Line )
                                  .ThenBy( x => x.Number )
                                  .Partition( (prev,curr) => curr.Line == prev.Line && curr.Number - prev.Number == 1.0 )
                                  .ToList() ;
```

Easy!

Comment: Worked really well. Great solution!